# Как сделать навигацию в приложении Андроид удобной для пользователя?

Tags: android, c#, activity, xamarin, mobile

Перечитал кучу статей, нашел много способов перехода между Activity, но не понял как же все-таки делают приложения профессионалы..в какой момент блокируют кнопку "назад", в какой момент заменяют ей действие. в какой момент лучше уничтожать Активити, а в какой момент оставить на Pause. Ответ можно не объяснять, а дать ссылку на подходящую статью или видео...(на русском...).